# different result in np.histogram() vs cv2.calcHist()

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, histogram

I'm trying to calculate the histogram of some images, but I've seen that the results that I got from np.histogram() are different from those of cv2.calcHist().

for example:

```
img_1 = array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.1137255 , 0.37254903,
       0.5294118 , 0.5568628 , 0.54901963, 0.6431373 , 0.6039216 ,
       0.57254905, 0.5254902 , 0.6117647 , 0.49411768, 0.4156863 ,
       0.427451  , 0.454902  , 0.44705886, 0.47450984, 0.5921569 ,
       0.74509805, 0.85098046, 0.7843138 , 0.8235295 , 0.77647066,
       0.82745105, 0.79215693, 0.78823537, 0.69411767, 0.5686275 ,
       0.5647059 , 0.54509807, 0.        , 0.        , 0.0509804 ,
       0.10588236, 0.5176471 , 0.59607846, 0.62352943, 0.52156866,
       0.5882353 , 0.59607846, 0.6862745 , 0.5176471 , 0.4784314 ,
       0.4666667 , 0.4666667 , 0.3921569 , 0.5764706 , 0.49411768,
       0.5803922 , 0.52156866, 0.7568628 , 0.77647066, 0.46274513,
       0.7568628 , 0.882353  , 0.8117648 , 0.86274517, 0.8745099 ,
       0.7411765 , 0.6156863 , 0.54901963, 0.43529415, 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.15294118, 0.38431376, 0.5764706 ,
       0.58431375, 0.5058824 , 0.5764706 , 0.5882353 , 0.5294118 ,
       0.4156863 , 0.53333336, 0.5568628 , 0.60784316, 0.6       ,
       0.69803923, 0.5921569 , 0.48627454, 0.6156863 , 0.77647066,
       0.5137255 , 0.20000002, 0.4666667 , 0.77647066, 0.83921576,
       0.7686275 , 0.81568635, 0.76470596, 0.8235295 , 0.69803923,
       0.5568628 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.04313726,
       0.23137257, 0.54509807, 0.4901961 , 0.45098042, 0.47450984,
       0.48235297, 0.44705886, 0.4901961 , 0.56078434, 0.627451  ,
       0.5921569 , 0.5803922 , 0.6431373 , 0.59607846, 0.65882355,
       0.80392164, 0.654902  , 0.21960786, 0.15294118, 0.2901961 ,
       0.59607846, 0.8196079 , 0.75294125, 0.7411765 , 0.73333335,
       0.89019614, 0.7294118 , 0.67058825, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.12156864, 0.31764707, 0.41176474,
       0.30980393, 0.47450984, 0.454902  , 0.5294118 , 0.52156866,
       0.5529412 , 0.627451  , 0.6313726 , 0.67058825, 0.7607844 ,
       0.7568628 , 0.854902  , 0.6666667 , 0.3137255 , 0.21176472,
       0.23529413, 0.20784315, 0.43137258, 0.7411765 , 0.8705883 ,
       0.81568635, 0.73333335, 0.8470589 , 0.76470596, 0.78823537,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.07843138, 0.1764706 , 0.4431373 , 0.5686275 , 0.47450984,
       0.58431375, 0.5568628 , 0.60784316, 0.6509804 , 0.79215693,
       0.79215693, 0.75294125, 0.7411765 , 0.7372549 , 0.4039216 ,
       0.14509805, 0.20392159, 0.24313727, 0.2627451 , 0.3019608 ,
       0.6627451 , 0.89019614, 0.83921576, 0.77647066, 0.74509805,
       0.7960785 , 0.78823537, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.09411766, 0.07058824, 0.4901961 , 0.48627454,
       0.5921569 , 0.57254905, 0.72156864, 0.69803923, 0.6627451 ,
       0.7568628 , 0.80392164, 0.8196079 , 0.6784314 , 0.8000001 ,
       0.58431375, 0.28627452, 0.17254902, 0.18039216, 0.18823531,
       0.18039216, 0.20392159, 0.3254902 , 0.8313726 , 0.79215693,
       0.86666673, 0.6745098 , 0.64705884, 0.6       , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.09411766, 0.16078432,
       0.57254905, 0.46274513, 0.60784316, 0.67058825, 0.7254902 ,
       0.69803923, 0.67058825, 0.7411765 , 0.6745098 , 0.67058825,
       0.7411765 , 0.82745105, 0.50980395, 0.2509804 , 0.24705884,
       0.26666668, 0.23137257, 0.24313727, 0.29411766, 0.22352943,
       0.5372549 , 0.82745105, 0.90196085, 0.8196079 , 0.6901961 ,
       0.6509804 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.14509805, 0.18431373, 0.5176471 , 0.6117647 , 0.5568628 ,
       0.7294118 , 0.7686275 , 0.7490196 , 0.5529412 , 0.5411765 ,
       0.57254905, 0.62352943, 0.6901961 , 0.8196079 , 0.45098042,
       0.21568629, 0.26666668, 0.25882354, 0.2392157 , 0.36862746,
       0.43921572, 0.35686275, 0.2901961 , 0.7176471 , 0.8431373 ,
       0.8745099 , 0.8431373 , 0.6627451 , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.16078432, 0.2627451 , 0.4901961 ,
       0.56078434, 0.60784316, 0.7176471 , 0.7254902 , 0.6       ,
       0.54901963, 0.5529412 , 0.45098042, 0.6156863 , 0.61960787,
       0.8117648 , 0.427451  , 0.3372549 , 0.45098042, 0.48627454,
       0.38823533, 0.4156863 , 0.48627454, 0.56078434, 0.5058824 ,
       0.54509807, 0.7960785 , 0.7294118 , 0.90196085, 0.73333335,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.12941177,
       0.27450982, 0.6156863 , 0.5411765 , 0.58431375, 0.73333335,
       0.6392157 , 0.5882353 , 0.5372549 , 0.5647059 , 0.49411768,
       0.5647059 , 0.6117647 , 0.7725491 , 0.4666667 , 0.58431375,
       0.5882353 , 0.5764706 , 0.5647059 , 0.62352943, 0.627451  ,
       0.60784316, 0.54901963, 0.6       , 0.6862745 , 0.7294118 ,
       0.8745099 , 0.8196079 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.24313727, 0.6156863 , 0.52156866,
       0.5803922 , 0.5686275 , 0.5647059 , 0.56078434, 0.6       ,
       0.46274513, 0.57254905, 0.5686275 , 0.8000001 , 0.7686275 ,
       0.6039216 , 0.6       , 0.52156866, 0.54901963, 0.5568628 ,
       0.5921569 , 0.7176471 , 0.6117647 , 0.54509807, 0.4666667 ,
       0.5686275 , 0.6901961 , 0.7019608 , 0.8352942 , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.2509804 ,
       0.5647059 , 0.64705884, 0.61960787, 0.5568628 , 0.5294118 ,
       0.5294118 , 0.56078434, 0.54901963, 0.5254902 , 0.627451  ,
       0.7490196 , 0.72156864, 0.6039216 , 0.49411768, 0.6       ,
       0.45882356, 0.54901963, 0.5647059 , 0.58431375, 0.73333335,
       0.7058824 , 0.39607847, 0.5254902 , 0.6431373 , 0.62352943,
       0.80392164, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.1254902 , 0.47450984, 0.61960787, 0.5529412 ,
       0.5803922 , 0.5294118 , 0.5529412 , 0.5411765 , 0.5803922 ,
       0.5647059 , 0.6901961 , 0.7294118 , 0.7137255 , 0.58431375,
       0.52156866, 0.62352943, 0.48627454, 0.5921569 , 0.61960787,
       0.6       , 0.7058824 , 0.76470596, 0.3529412 , 0.3019608 ,
       0.69411767, 0.7411765 , 0.654902  , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.3019608 ,
       0.48627454, 0.5764706 , 0.454902  , 0.43921572, 0.4431373 ,
       0.56078434, 0.5058824 , 0.6901961 , 0.7490196 , 0.8000001 ,
       0.7686275 , 0.67058825, 0.60784316, 0.5803922 , 0.654902  ,
       0.5764706 , 0.6392157 , 0.61960787, 0.6627451 , 0.59607846,
       0.3921569 , 0.3137255 , 0.67058825, 0.8941177 , 0.70980394,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.20000002, 0.6392157 , 0.32941177,
       0.2901961 , 0.52156866, 0.50980395, 0.54901963, 0.8196079 ,
       0.8313726 , 0.8196079 , 0.7960785 , 0.54509807, 0.5529412 ,
       0.6431373 , 0.69803923, 0.6431373 , 0.63529414, 0.654902  ,
       0.6666667 , 0.3254902 , 0.40784317, 0.41176474, 0.68235296,
       0.8745099 , 0.7803922 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.13333334,
       0.45098042, 0.49411768, 0.25882354, 0.54509807, 0.54901963,
       0.6627451 , 0.8117648 , 0.82745105, 0.854902  , 0.77647066,
       0.58431375, 0.5803922 , 0.61960787, 0.60784316, 0.6156863 ,
       0.5568628 , 0.6666667 , 0.62352943, 0.30588236, 0.24313727,
       0.4784314 , 0.7058824 , 0.7725491 , 0.7725491 , 0.2509804 ,
       0.3019608 , 0.16470589, 0.31764707, 0.8078432 , 0.46274513,
       0.20784315, 0.08235294, 0.27450982, 0.6431373 , 0.49803925,
       0.5294118 , 0.6431373 , 0.6745098 , 0.7490196 , 0.8078432 ,
       0.8588236 , 0.8235295 , 0.7490196 , 0.63529414, 0.61960787,
       0.5803922 , 0.6313726 , 0.53333336, 0.6313726 , 0.5254902 ,
       0.37647063, 0.28627452, 0.5686275 , 0.882353  , 0.7254902 ,
       0.7686275 , 0.26666668, 0.31764707, 0.40784317, 0.32156864,
       0.26666668, 0.04705883, 0.11764707, 0.12941177, 0.21568629,
       0.427451  , 0.654902  , 0.6666667 , 0.7254902 , 0.6509804 ,
       0.7490196 , 0.89019614, 0.8980393 , 0.8588236 , 0.8235295 ,
       0.6627451 , 0.7137255 , 0.5921569 , 0.5686275 , 0.654902  ,
       0.5294118 , 0.38823533, 0.35686275, 0.3019608 , 0.6156863 ,
       0.80392164, 0.75294125, 0.7490196 , 0.3647059 , 0.20784315,
       0.2784314 , 0.2901961 , 0.23137257, 0.21176472, 0.28627452,
       0.19607845, 0.40000004, 0.22352943, 0.45882356, 0.7960785 ,
       0.5803922 , 0.5294118 , 0.7686275 , 0.8000001 , 0.85098046,
       0.83921576, 0.7686275 , 0.80392164, 0.6745098 , 0.654902  ,
       0.5568628 , 0.6431373 , 0.41176474, 0.3254902 , 0.30588236,
       0.63529414, 0.8196079 , 0.6745098 , 0.76470596, 0.7568628 ,
       0.28235295, 0.30980393, 0.3019608 , 0.20784315, 0.34509805,
       0.20392159, 0.23529413, 0.20784315, 0.29803923, 0.28627452,
       0.29411766, 0.54509807, 0.68235296, 0.52156866, 0.65882355,
       0.64705884, 0.70980394, 0.75294125, 0.86666673, 0.73333335,
       0.56078434, 0.6392157 , 0.6745098 , 0.4431373 , 0.20784315,
       0.3019608 , 0.63529414, 0.8980393 , 0.7607844 , 0.77647066,
       0.75294125, 0.7176471 , 0.2627451 , 0.3647059 , 0.30980393,
       0.25882354, 0.29411766, 0.20392159, 0.29803923, 0.5372549 ,
       0.3647059 , 0.27450982, 0.2784314 , 0.25490198, 0.5058824 ,
       0.7176471 , 0.5686275 , 0.654902  , 0.63529414, 0.73333335,
       0.70980394, 0.67058825, 0.6431373 , 0.68235296, 0.38823533,
       0.3529412 , 0.15686275, 0.5254902 , 0.9058824 , 0.8000001 ,
       0.78823537, 0.7411765 , 0.7019608 , 0.74509805, 0.26666668,
       0.2509804 , 0.19215688, 0.2509804 , 0.27058825, 0.21568629,
       0.58431375, 0.7411765 , 0.40784317, 0.2784314 , 0.2627451 ,
       0.27058825, 0.32156864, 0.4666667 , 0.81568635, 0.6117647 ,
       0.4901961 , 0.5882353 , 0.7137255 , 0.7686275 , 0.74509805,
       0.5411765 , 0.34901962, 0.34509805, 0.4156863 , 0.7607844 ,
       0.8313726 , 0.7372549 , 0.81568635, 0.7058824 , 0.6862745 ,
       0.78823537, 0.26666668, 0.34117648, 0.29803923, 0.20784315,
       0.25490198, 0.31764707, 0.59607846, 0.6784314 , 0.3529412 ,
       0.40784317, 0.40000004, 0.18431373, 0.3529412 , 0.29803923,
       0.5294118 , 0.7019608 , 0.5137255 , 0.32156864, 0.5176471 ,
       0.64705884, 0.5411765 , 0.34901962, 0.38431376, 0.49803925,
       0.7607844 , 0.78823537, 0.76470596, 0.82745105, 0.73333335,
       0.6784314 , 0.7294118 , 0.7960785 , 0.18039216, 0.2627451 ,
       0.3137255 , 0.29411766, 0.32156864, 0.33333334, 0.427451  ,
       0.5882353 , 0.45882356, 0.38431376, 0.4431373 , 0.36078432,
       0.30588236, 0.3137255 , 0.21176472, 0.45882356, 0.6156863 ,
       0.61960787, 0.28627452, 0.33333334, 0.31764707, 0.3372549 ,
       0.5058824 , 0.80392164, 0.85098046, 0.7607844 , 0.81568635,
       0.77647066, 0.7019608 , 0.6784314 , 0.8196079 , 0.81568635,
       0.27058825, 0.17254902, 0.28235295, 0.3372549 , 0.3019608 ,
       0.26666668, 0.18039216, 0.43137258, 0.6156863 , 0.60784316,
       0.8117648 , 0.7568628 , 0.69411767, 0.39607847, 0.24705884,
       0.25882354, 0.30980393, 0.47058827, 0.59607846, 0.41960788,
       0.32941177, 0.42352945, 0.86666673, 0.8705883 , 0.7843138 ,
       0.7137255 , 0.7960785 , 0.7568628 , 0.7019608 , 0.69803923,
       0.7725491 , 0.8235295 , 0.25490198, 0.23529413, 0.28235295,
       0.26666668, 0.2627451 , 0.29411766, 0.18431373, 0.5529412 ,
       0.8470589 , 0.8470589 , 0.882353  , 0.7254902 , 0.8588236 ,
       0.7137255 , 0.5921569 , 0.5647059 , 0.5254902 , 0.3647059 ,
       0.3019608 , 0.44705886, 0.5647059 , 0.6901961 , 0.8352942 ,
       0.8117648 , 0.80392164, 0.82745105, 0.854902  , 0.77647066,
       0.73333335, 0.67058825, 0.7725491 , 0.8431373 , 0.28627452,
       0.227451  , 0.33333334, 0.26666668, 0.2784314 , 0.20392159,
       0.43921572, 0.8862746 , 0.7960785 , 0.7843138 , 0.8470589 ,
       0.74509805, 0.81568635, 0.7294118 , 0.8235295 , 0.79215693,
       0.7960785 , 0.80392164, 0.4156863 , 0.49803925, 0.79215693,
       0.75294125, 0.8078432 , 0.81568635, 0.75294125, 0.7686275 ,
       0.8588236 , 0.79215693, 0.8000001 , 0.74509805, 0.7490196 ,
       0.85098046, 0.34117648, 0.29803923, 0.34901962, 0.29411766,
       0.227451  , 0.31764707, 0.7411765 , 0.79215693, 0.7843138 ,
       0.8588236 , 0.85098046, 0.8705883 , 0.8745099 , 0.8000001 ,
       0.7607844 , 0.79215693, 0.78823537, 0.82745105, 0.75294125,
       0.7686275 , 0.854902  , 0.7803922 , 0.81568635, 0.69411767,
       0.74509805, 0.7843138 , 0.7725491 , 0.7294118 , 0.7294118 ,
       0.7843138 , 0.7725491 , 0.82745105, 0.28627452, 0.40784317,
       0.24313727, 0.35686275, 0.4666667 , 0.77647066, 0.7843138 ,
       0.68235296, 0.8352942 , 0.86666673, 0.7411765 , 0.8000001 ,
       0.7803922 , 0.8705883 , 0.7294118 , 0.75294125, 0.7607844 ,
       0.74509805, 0.7843138 , 0.76470596, 0.77647066, 0.76470596,
       0.8117648 , 0.80392164, 0.7058824 , 0.78823537, 0.8196079 ,
       0.7960785 , 0.79215693, 0.7843138 , 0.882353  , 0.7960785 ,
       0.29803923, 0.25882354, 0.39607847, 0.6745098 , 0.89019614,
       0.8078432 , 0.75294125, 0.6784314 , 0.7803922 , 0.7568628 ,
       0.8431373 , 0.67058825, 0.7607844 , 0.79215693, 0.7490196 ,
       0.7490196 , 0.76470596, 0.7294118 , 0.83921576, 0.7686275 ,
       0.8078432 , 0.74509805, 0.8313726 , 0.86274517, 0.8000001 ,
       0.8352942 , 0.7960785 , 0.7607844 , 0.8235295 , 0.85098046,
       0.76470596, 0.7843138 , 0.32156864, 0.24313727, 0.58431375,
       1.        , 0.8352942 , 0.7803922 , 0.7490196 , 0.7137255 ,
       0.7607844 , 0.73333335, 0.74509805, 0.75294125, 0.7568628 ,
       0.7411765 , 0.8196079 , 0.6901961 , 0.76470596, 0.72156864,
       0.6666667 , 0.8000001 , 0.76470596, 0.7490196 , 0.8352942 ,
       0.7372549 , 0.8980393 , 0.9058824 , 0.75294125, 0.73333335,
       0.80392164, 0.8196079 , 0.79215693, 0.7137255 ], dtype=float32)
```

```
hist_img_1 = np.histogram(img_1.ravel(), bins=10, range=(0.0,1.0))
cv_hist_img_1 = cv2.calcHist([img_1.ravel()], [0], None, [10], [0.0,1.0])
```

These are the results:

hist_img_1:

```
(array([ 83,  29, 104,  75,  86, 155, 146, 209, 132,   5]),
 array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ],
       dtype=float32))
```

cv_hist_img_1:

```
array([[ 83.],
       [ 29.],
       [104.],
       [ 75.],
       [ 86.],
       [155.],
       [146.],
       [209.],
       [132.],
       [  4.]], dtype=float32)
```

As you can see, the last count in hist_img_1 is different from that in cv_hist_img_1.

Could the problem be the inclusiveness of range parameter?? I think (not sure, can't see anything in docs) the range parameter in numpy is inclussive for both left and right values, while in cv2 is not for right value. In that sense, is it possible to make the cv2 right range parameter inclusive?

Thanks.

EDIT: The question was modified according to @Tim Roberts answer.

Answer (score 1):

numpy finds the min and max values in your array, and creates 10 bins evenly spaced between those values.  You can see the second array it returns, which has the values it computed for the edges of the bins  You told cv2 to make the bins spaced between 0 and 10.  It's a rather different task.

You can pass numpy an integer range of bin edges.

Comment: easy solution :) Thanks! however, for my images the last value of counts is different for both methods, np.histogram() gives a greater value. I don´t know why?? I set the ranges equal for both methods. You have an idea?

Comment: OpenCV treats the bins like Python, where the high end is exclusive.  So, the final bin in your example ends at but does not include 1.0, and you have one sample of exactly 1.0.  OpenCV doesn't put that in a bin.